# problem with the "big-o" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, user-interface

I noticed a curious problem, during retagging a question I wanted to add the [big-o](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-o) tag to a question but the tag doesn't show up when you type "big-" in the tag box

I think it is because it is (by use) the fourth tag containing "big-" 
(the others being [big-list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list), [big-picture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-picture) and [big-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-numbers)).

But also it is the only mathematical term in the "big-" list.

Is there a possibility to show the tag somehow?

Comment: It's the *most* used of the four tags, not the least; the tags have $1600$, $600$, $60$ and $50$ questions respectively, approximately.

Comment: But [tag:big-o] is just a synonym of [tag:asymptotics].

Comment: If the question is specifically about Big-O notation (rather than simply a problem involving it) then using the two tags [tag:asymptotics] and [tag:notation] would be appropriate.

Comment: This seems similar to the following problem: [Existing tag not shown when searching in the list of tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224818/existing-tag-not-shown-when-searching-in-the-list-of-tags)